# Devise Google Oauth works perfectly but doesn't sign-in on user creation, requires additional log on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, helper

I have Devise running on my Rails 3.2 application. Google Oauth is used to sign in.

New Users attempt to sign in with Google and are redirected to the sign-in page without being signed in. I check the DB and the User's accounts are created with the correct credentials (everything is correct except IP).

Returning Users have no problem signing in, Log out also works perfectly.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I followed this tutorial: http://blogs.burnsidedigital.com/2013/03/rails-3-devise-omniauth-and-google/

The difference is that I do not have any need for additional user information, I just want to authenticate users through their google accounts ensuring they belong to a certain domain `foobar.com`

I have an OmniAuth controller which looks like this:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def google_oauth2
      auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      proceeder = !!(auth.info.email =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@foobar\.com$/)
        if proceeder
          user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
            flash.notice = "Signed in!"
            sign_in_and_redirect user
            redirect_to :root
        else
          flash[:notice] = "You must use an email ending in @foobar.com"
          redirect_to signup_path
        end
```

and my User model is as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes
  has_many :reports
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable#, :omniauth_providers => [:google_oauth2]
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      if user = User.find_by_email(auth.info.email)
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user
      else
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
          user.provider = auth.provider
          user.uid = auth.uid
          user.email = auth.info.email
          user
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

For visitors who are not signed in I call `posts#login`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
...
def login
    Rails.logger.debug(current_user)
    if current_user
            redirect_to :root
    end
end
...
```

and the `root_path` contains a `current_user` check which redirects to `posts#login` if no user is logged in.

I thought the problem was within the method `sign_in_and_redirect` so I added the following to my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  serialization_scope :view_context

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    root_url
  end
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    root_url
  end
end
```

Why aren't new accounts signed in? Why would their accounts be created but not logged in?

Any help is greatly appreciated, I am completely stumped (Devise documentation didn't lead me to a solution).

#### EDIT

Here are the development logs of a new user signing in/up:

```
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop


Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-16 16:58:54 -0500
Processing by PostsController#login as HTML

  Rendered posts/login.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 30.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
(google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-16 16:58:56 -0500
(google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=e5c02458190b79758da474baa623717a29078427ad6049f7&code=4/yimrxaCXMOY_FTZyAgd_-CpZxMrF.EhatByjkrMkYshQV0ieZDAoQx9zFhAI" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-16 16:59:00 -0500
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"e5c02458190b79758da474baa623717a29078427ad6049f7", "code"=>"4/yimrxaCXMOY_FTZyAgd_-CpZxMrF.EhatByjkrMkYshQV0ieZDAoQx9zFhAI"}
  User Load (54.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jquadr01@foobar.com' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = 'google_oauth2' AND "users"."uid" = '105565017494971239846' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'jquadr01@foobar.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (76.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "provider", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 16 Nov 2013 21:59:01 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_at", Sat, 16 Nov 2013 21:59:01 UTC +00:00], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["email", "jquadr01@foobar.com"], ["encrypted_password", ""], ["last_sign_in_at", Sat, 16 Nov 2013 21:59:01 UTC +00:00], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1"], ["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["uid", "1055650112345678911846"], ["updated_at", Sat, 16 Nov 2013 21:59:01 UTC +00:00]]
   (16.9ms)  COMMIT
#<User:0x000000020d7a08>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 338ms (ActiveRecord: 162.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-16 16:59:01 -0500
Processing by MainController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/signup
Completed 302 Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-16 16:59:01 -0500
Processing by PostsController#login as HTML

  Rendered posts/login.html.erb within layouts/application (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0m
```

Comment: Do you see any warnings in your log regarding CSRF?

Comment: I do not but I am using this gem https://github.com/xrd/ng-rails-csrf if that helps

Comment: I attached the logs to the question

Comment: Try adding protect_from_forgery with: :exception to your application controller. If its related to CSRF, you will see an exception instead of a 'null' session, which is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You say “New Users attempt to sign in with Google and are redirected to the sign-in page without being signed in” and I’m not 100% sure what that means.  Every time you use Google OAuth to let someone into your app, they’re going to see a one-time approval screen so they get a chance to say whether or not they’re OK with their identity being sent to your app.  They really shouldn’t be going to the *sign-in* page if they’re already signed in.  Which page do they go to?

Comment: I have my own user table which new users are saved to (after oauth redirects and gives me the OK). When a user is signed in they are signed in if they exist in the user db table, else they are a new user and have a new record created for them. Signing in requires creating a session variable that is accessed by a `user_signed_in?` helper method. The sign in page is just a google button which leads to the google sign in and eventually a callback

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't read your code. Following on from Tim's answer and your comment, you seem to be confusing "new user" with "logged in" user. A new user will only be logged in while his session is extant. Once the session expires, he is "logged out". Oauth has nothing to do with user sessions, so I suspect this confusion may be the cause of your problem. You need to manage your own sessions.

Comment: Okay yes I understand this, but devise manages the sessions. Read my code

Answer (score 1):

As described here, add the following code to your OmniauthCallbacksController:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

The user isn't signed in because of CSRF authentication failure. In Rails 4, if the CSRF authentication fails, the default behaviour is :null_session, which is why the user isn't signed in.

**EDIT :**

The issue seems to be with the code that creates a new user in the `User.from_omniauth` method. You're creating a new user, if one doesn't exist with a given provider and uid, without setting the email attribute, which can't be blank! Consequently, validation fails and the user object is not persisted, and hence there's no valid session.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a CSRF error. If it were, there would be a warning in the log.

Comment: so should I do if user.persisted?

Comment: @anuj-arora Good point, although that conflicts with jquadrin's statement that the users are being created in the DB.

Comment: Looks like email is, in fact, being set. It was just chopped off in the example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a sure solution, but I have an idea.

Consider this code:

```
if proceeder
  user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
    flash.notice = "Signed in!"
    sign_in_and_redirect user
    redirect_to :root
```

Notice that you're triggering two redirects. First you call the devise redirect, and then you call `redirect_to :root`. Normally, if you issue two redirects in the same action, it results in an `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError`. The fact that you're not getting a `DoubleRenderError` is a clue that something is not right with `sign_in_and_redirect`.

Now, I don't know what's wrong with `sign_in_and_redirect`, so let's examine the source:

```
# File 'lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb', line 159
def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)
  options  = args.extract_options!
  scope    = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  resource = args.last || resource_or_scope
  sign_in(scope, resource, options)
  redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with finding the user scope, since the rest of it looks okay, and perhaps your mappings are not configured correctly.

In order to avoid any ambiguity (as well as the `DoubleRenderError` that I would *expect* to be happening), try replacing the above code with this:

```
if proceeder
  user = User.from_omniauth(auth)
    flash.notice = "Signed in!"
    sign_in :user, user
    redirect_to :root
```

Let me know if that works, and if not, I'll take another crack at it.

P.S. do you see the flash message "Signed in!" after you authenticate with Google?

Comment: Would you post the rest of the `self.from_omniauth` method?

Comment: I just posted it, I didnt realize it got cut off

Comment: Would you please print out `user.inspect` after your line `user = User.from_omniauth(auth)` and paste it here so we can see how the user object is being created?

Comment: I can debug on my own if thats the case, the attributes for `User` are all present and being created correctly